# Converting NGINX rule to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to convert the following NGINX rule:

```
location ~ "^/calendrier/[0-9]{4}" {
    rewrite ^/calendrier/(.*)$ /calendar/$1;
}
```

to .htaccess. I tried:

```
RewriteCond ^/calendrier/[0-9]{4} [NC]
RewriteRule ^/calendrier/(.*)$ /calendar/$1 [QSA,L]
```

but it isn't working.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the rewrite I used to get the job done.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/calendrier/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^calendrier/(.*)$ /calendar/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to review the `mod_rewrite` documentation before attempting to convert rules from other platforms. Reason being: it is essential that you understand *exactly* how `mod_rewrite` should be used so that conversions are painless.

The problem with your conversion is that the `RewriteCond` is not checking that pattern against anything. Essentially, you've just done guess-work to see if it does what you want.

You only need to place the following in your **`/.htaccess`** file:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^calendier/([0-9]{4})/?$ /calendar/$1 [L]
```

The first part of the rule checks for `calendier/<some_number>` with an optional trailing slash (If you do not want the slash, you can remove `/?`).